# Completely standardized indirect effect (Preacher & Kelley, 2011) in lavaan

Tags: effect-size, mediation, lavaan

Preacher & Kelley (2011) have proposed an effect size (i.e., completely standardized indirect effect) that quantifies the magnitude of an indirect effect. My question is whether lavaan's `Std.all` represents this effect size, or whether there are distinctions?

Preacher, K. J., & Kelley, K. (2011). Effect size measures for mediation models: Quantitative strategies for communicating indirect effects. Psychological Methods, 16(2), 93–115. https://doi.org/10.1037/a0022658

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's not forget that "completely standardized indirect effect"  is simply the product of standardized regression coefficients, which is not directly attributable to Preacher & Kelley (2011) and is in fact quite old.

So yes, having the `Std.all` argument in `lavaan` will give you standardized effects and thus standardized indirect effects.

Mathematically, the standardized effect is obtained from $\beta_{xy} = b_{xy}\frac{\sigma_x}{\sigma_y}$, or by standardizing all the variables so that $\sigma_x = \sigma_y = 1$. The "completely standardized indirect effect" is obtained from  $$\beta_{xm} \beta_{my}= b_{xm}\frac{\sigma_x}{\sigma_m}b_{my}\frac{\sigma_m}{\sigma_y}=b_{xm}b_{my}\frac{\sigma_x}{\sigma_y},$$ or by standardizing all the variables.